# Destruction of the World: Parshas Noach vs. the Rambam

Tags: rambam, parashat-noach

In Parshas Noach, it is written:

> וַֽהֲקִֽמֹתִ֤י אֶת־בְּרִיתִי֙ אִתְּכֶ֔ם וְלֹֽא־יִכָּרֵ֧ת כָּל־בָּשָׂ֛ר
> ע֖וֹד מִמֵּ֣י הַמַּבּ֑וּל וְלֹא־יִֽהְיֶ֥ה ע֛וֹד מַבּ֖וּל לְשַׁחֵ֥ת
> הָאָֽרֶץ:
>
> And I will establish My covenant with you, and never again will all flesh be cut off by the flood waters, and there will never again be a
> flood to destroy the earth.

However, the Rambam writes in Mishneh Torah, Repentance 3,

> וְכֵן כָּל הָעוֹלָם כֻּלּוֹ אִם הָיוּ עֲוֹנוֹתֵיהֶם מְרֻבִּין מִזְּכֻיּוֹתֵיהֶן מִיָּד הֵן נִשְׁחָתִין
>
> ...So, too, is the whole world, if their vices exceeded their virtues they are presently destroyed.

If there is a contradiction between these two sources, how can it be solved? If there is not a contradiction, can the world be destroyed, just not through the use of a flood? Was Hashem implying that there *is* a possibility that the world may be destroyed, but such a thing will not happen?

Comment: How do you understand this statement of the Rambam - אָדָם שֶׁעֲוֹנוֹתָיו מְרֻבִּין עַל זְכֻיּוֹתָיו מִיָּד הוּא מֵת בְּרִשְׁעוֹ - ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two loopholes in the verse: 1. It only mentions water, but other destructive forces such as fire and plague are not included. 2. It says "all flesh" will not be destroyed but some people could be drowned. As the Tosefta [says](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.9.15?lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Tosefta_Ta%27anit.2&lang2=bi)

> רמ"א מבול של מים אין אבל מבול של אש ושל גפרית יש כדרך שהביא על הסדומיים שנאמר (בראשית י״ט:כ״ד) וה' המטיר על סדום וגו' רבי יהודה אומר מבול של כל בשר אין אבל מבול של יחידים יש כיצד נפל לים טבעה ספינתו בים ומת הרי הוא מבולו רבי יוסי אומר מבול של מים אין אבל מבול של דבר לעובדי כוכבים לימות המשיח יש שנא' (זכריה י״א:י׳) ואקח את מקלי את נועם וגו' מהו אומר ותופר ביום ההוא.

The [Gemara](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.11a?lang=bi) in Maseches Sotah says that the Egyptians made this mistake when they chose to drown the Jewish children.

> אלא בואו ונדונם במים שכבר נשבע הקב"ה שאינו מביא מבול לעולם שנאמר (ישעיהו נד, ט) כי מי נח זאת לי וגו' והן אינן יודעין שעל כל העולם כולו אינו מביא אבל על אומה אחת הוא מביא.    Rather, let us come and judge them with water, by drowning the Jewish babies. God will not punish us with water, for the Holy One, Blessed be He, already took an oath that He will not bring a flood upon the world, as it is stated: “For this is as the waters of Noah unto Me; for as I have sworn that the waters of Noah should no more go over the earth” (Isaiah 54:9). The Gemara comments: And Pharaoh’s advisors did not know that He will not bring a flood upon all the world, but He may bring destruction by water upon one nation.